# Javascript operator "in" doesn't work well with floating numbers

Tags: javascript

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) document. the `in` operator can check whether a specified value is in a specified object.

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain

I have the below code:

```js
var array = [1.1,2.1];
var status = 1.1 in array;
console.log(status);
```

the output is `false`. However, I expect to get the `true` instead.

another code:

```
var array = [1,2];
var status = 1 in array;
console.log(status);
```

the output is `true`.

## Question

1. why integer can work well with the `in` operator and the floating numbers can't?
2. what is the working mechanism of the `in` operator?

Comment: `array.includes(1.1)`

Comment: The `in` operator tests whether a key does exist in an object, not whether an array includes a value

Comment: @MoritzRoessler what happened when `in` applied on an array?

Comment: the code `1 in [1,2]` can work well, so why floating numbers can't?

Comment: @V.Wu It tests, whether an array has a **key** `1`, since your array is of length `2` it has the keys `0` and `1`. Try `2 in [1,2]`. It returns *false* because your array does not have a key `2`. Try `2 in [1,2,3]` and it returns *true*.

Comment: I got it, it is a too silly question :)

Comment: Thank you, I think I am going to close this question. this question doesn't include any valuable things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the MDN document. the in operator can check whether a specified value is in a specified object

No. It says **property**, not value.

There is no `array[1.1]`. The members of the array have integer property names (`0` and `1` for an array of length 2).

e.g.

```js
var array = [1.1, 2.1];
console.log("length" in array, array.length);
console.log(0 in array, array[0]);
console.log("find" in array, array.find);

// And it works perfectly well for floats if there is a matching property to find

var object = { "1.1": "hello, world" };
console.log(1.1 in object, object[1.1]);
```

Use [the `includes` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to test for the presence of a **value** in an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the find function.

The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise it returns undefined

```js
const array = [1.1,2.1];
const status = array.find(element => element == 1.1);
console.log(status);
```